# Sealed Trait / Object Case Class Byte Code Changed from 2.9.1. to 2.9.2?

Tags: scala, scala-2.9, scala-java-interop

## Same source file in both directories

I have the following sealed trait in Errors.scala that I would like to reference in a Java class.  In Scala 2.9.1, I was able to reference Errors.TooBig from Java as Errors$TooBig$  That no longer compiles in 2.9.2.

Errors.scala

```
package com.abc

sealed trait Error

object Errors {
  case object TooBig extends Error
}
```

JavaTest.java

```
import com.abc.Errors$TooBig$;
public class JavaTest {
}
```

I have the same source files in two different directories (2.9.1/2.9.2).  I am able to compile the source using 2.9.1, but not 2.9.2.

```
>2.9.1$ brew switch scala 2.9.1
>2.9.1$ scalac Errors.scala
>2.9.1$ javac -classpath .:/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.9.1/libexec/lib/scala-library.jar JavaTest.java
>2.9.1$
>2.9.1$ cd ../2.9.2
>2.9.2$ brew switch scala 2.9.2
>2.9.2$ scalac Errors.scala
>2.9.2$ javac -classpath .:/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.9.2/libexec/lib/scala-library.jar JavaTest.java
JavaTest.java:1: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Errors$TooBig$
location: package com.abc
import com.abc.Errors$TooBig$;
              ^
1 error
}
}
```

Here is a diff of the javap dump of the com.abc.Errors$TooBig$ class files:

```
mhughes:~/scalatest$ diff 2.9.1/TooBig.txt 2.9.2/TooBig.txt 
2c2
< public final class com.abc.Errors$TooBig$ extends java.lang.Object implements com.abc.Error,scala.ScalaObject,scala.Product,scala.Serializable
---
> public final class com.abc.Errors$TooBig$ extends java.lang.Object implements com.abc.Error,scala.Product,scala.Serializable
5a6,7
>   InnerClass: 
>    public final #68= #9 of #67; //TooBig$=class com/abc/Errors$TooBig$ of class com/abc/Errors
73,80c75,84
< const #65 = Asciz com/abc/Error;
< const #66 = class #65;    //  com/abc/Error
< const #67 = Asciz scala/ScalaObject;
< const #68 = class #67;    //  scala/ScalaObject
< const #69 = Asciz scala/Product;
< const #70 = class #69;    //  scala/Product
< const #71 = Asciz scala/Serializable;
< const #72 = class #71;    //  scala/Serializable
---
> const #65 = Asciz InnerClasses;
> const #66 = Asciz com/abc/Errors;
> const #67 = class #66;    //  com/abc/Errors
> const #68 = Asciz TooBig$;
> const #69 = Asciz com/abc/Error;
> const #70 = class #69;    //  com/abc/Error
> const #71 = Asciz scala/Product;
> const #72 = class #71;    //  scala/Product
> const #73 = Asciz scala/Serializable;
> const #74 = class #73;    //  scala/Serializable
```

You can see that there clearly is a class called 'Errors$TooBig$' generated by both 2.9.1 and 2.9.2.

Answer (score 2):

You should not rely on class names for retrieving scala objects from Java. You can write a static factory designed to be called from Java:

```
package com.abc

sealed trait Error

object Errors {
  case object TooBig extends Error

  //Java API
  def getTooBig(): Error = TooBig
}
```

Then, call it from Java with:

```
import com.abc.*;

Error tooBig = Errors.getTooBig();
```